# Работа цикла do while

Tags: java

Почему только один раз выводится код? Вроде же правильно сделал.

```
    class Loops3 {
        public static void main (String[] args) {
            String[] xml = {"XML", "in", "easy", "steps"};
            int k = 0;
            if (xml.length > 0) 
                do {        
                    System.out.println("\t\txml["+k+"] - |" + xml[k]);
                    k++;
                } while (k < xml.length);
        }
    }
```

Вот таким должен быть вывод:

```
  xml[0] - |XML
  xml[1] - |in
  xml[2] - |easy
  xml[3] - |stepsxml[0] - |XML
      xml[1] - |in
      xml[2] - |easy
      xml[3] - |stepsxml[0] - |XML
          xml[1] - |in
          xml[2] - |easy
          xml[3] - |stepsxml[0] - |XML
              xml[1] - |in
              xml[2] - |easy
              xml[3] - |steps
```

Comment: я увидел 4 строки в sysout

Comment: Но мне надо чтобы вывод был цикла с проверкой условия: if (xml.length > 0). То есть 4 раза отработал цикл при выводе информации. Может я чего не понимаю...

Comment: Если ты всегда выводишь 2 табуляции, то откуда может взяться лесенка? Если цикл проходит по массиву только 1 раз, то откуда ещё значения? И зачем там этот if, если массив непустой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        class Loops3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String[] xml = {"XML", "in", "easy", "steps"};

            StringBuilder tab = new StringBuilder();

            for (int i = 0; i < xml.length; i++) {

                int k = 0;

                do {
                    if (k == 0) {
                        System.out.println("xml[" + k + "] - |" + xml[k]);
                    } else {

                        System.out.println(tab + "xml[" + k + "] - |" + xml[k]);
                    }
                    k++;

                } while (k < xml.length - 1);

                System.out.print(tab);

                tab.insert(0, "\t");

                System.out.print("xml[" + k + "] - |" + xml[k]);

            }
        }
```

Как то так....

Comment: Cпасибо, то что нужно)